# Why does an instance method-reference work for mismatching signatures?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

So I was doing some coding earlier and discovered that a function that has a signature that just takes `Function<FooClass, String>`, I can pass a method for a function of FooClass that produces a String (see example below).

So I've discovered that this is supported by java, I mean.. it compiles, and I've found an article [describing the feature here](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx#instance-method-reference-of-an-object-of-a-particular-type)

```java
public static class Foo {
    public String produceString() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}

public static String test(Function<Foo, String> produceString) {
    return produceString.apply(new Foo());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // WEIRD CODE BELOW!! Here's the method reference:
    String output = test(Foo::produceString);
    System.out.println(output);
    // Outputs "Hello world!"
}
```

My question is this: how the hell does java do this!?

Does anyone have an explanation for *why* this works?

Comment: It doesn't *take* a string, it *produces* a string, as its name suggests. What it takes is an instance of Foo.

Comment: @shmosel ahh good call, updated the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may treat Method Reference as syntactic sugar for create corresponding lambda expression:

```
String output = test(Foo::produceString);
```

given `produceString` is an instance method, above expression is equivalent to

```
String output = test( (Foo foo) -> foo.produceString() );
```

Comment: But you can't call `Foo.produceString()`! It isn't a static function, its an instance on Foo itself, so you would have to call `(new Foo()).produceString()`

Comment: Sorry my fault here, I misread your produceString.  However, it is jsut the same.  Lemme update the answer